# Concise, universal A* search in C#

Tags: c#, a-star

I was looking for an A* search implementation in C#. Eventually wrote my own. Because it's universal, I hope it will be useful for others.

Comment: Nothing wrong with sharing your knowledge like this.  But you should phrase the question portion as a question.

Comment: IMHO a good Stack Overflow question asks a specific question. Furthermore, if you're going to post an A* algorithm here, you should explain in your question why the many A* algorithms already available on the Internet do not address your specific need, and then the answer should show clearly how your specific example does address that specific need, which all the other examples on the Internet do not. Frankly, as you might imagine, it's a bit more challenging to create a canonical algorithm example Q&A on Stack Overflow than you may have originally realized. A code dump doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the algorithm, inherit a class from `AStar<T>` and override `Neighbors`, `Cost` and `Heuristic` functions to define your search domain. Type `T` defines a location in the search domain (for example Point when searching on a 2D grid). Then call `FindPath` on your class.

You may also optionally override `StorageClear`, `StorageGet` and `StorageAdd` to provide optimized per-location data storage for A*. The default implementation uses a `Dictionary<T, object>`, which is reasonably fast, but can be improved upon in many specific cases. If not overriding storage, make sure that type T is equatable (e.g. by implementing `IEquatable<T>`), otherwise dictionary lookups will be very slow.

See comments for more details.

```
public abstract class AStar<T>
{
    #region Fields

    private class Node
    {
        public T Position;
        public T PreviousPosition;
        public float F, G, H;
        public bool IsClosed;
    }

    private int m_nodesCacheIndex;
    private List<Node> m_nodesCache = new List<Node>();
    private List<Node> m_openHeap = new List<Node>();
    private List<T> m_neighbors = new List<T>();
    private Dictionary<T, object> m_defaultStorage;

    #endregion

    #region Domain Definition

    // User must override Neighbors, Cost and Heuristic functions to define search domain.
    // It is optional to override StorageClear, StorageGet and StorageAdd functions. 
    // Default implementation of these storage functions uses a Dictionary<T, object>, this works for all possible search domains. 
    // A domain-specific storage algorihm may be significantly faster.
    // For example if searching on a finite 2D or 3D grid, storage using fixed array with each element representing one world point benchmarks an order of magnitude faster.

    /// <summary>
    /// Return all neighbors of the given point.
    /// Must be overridden.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Point to return neighbors for</param>
    /// <param name="neighbors">Empty collection to fill with neighbors</param>
    protected abstract void Neighbors(T p, List<T> neighbors);

    /// <summary>
    /// Return cost of making a step from p1 to p2 (which are neighbors).
    /// Cost equal to float.PositiveInfinity indicates that passage from p1 to p2 is impossible.
    /// Must be overridden.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p1">Start point</param>
    /// <param name="p2">End point</param>
    /// <returns>Cost value</returns>
    protected abstract float Cost(T p1, T p2);

    /// <summary>
    /// Return an estimate of cost of moving from p to nearest goal.
    /// Must return 0 when p is goal.
    /// This is an estimate of sum of all costs along the best path between p and the nearest goal.
    /// This should not overestimate the actual cost; if it does, the result of A* might not be an optimal path.
    /// Underestimating the cost is allowed, but may cause the algorithm to check more positions.
    /// Must be overridden.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Point to estimate cost from</param>
    /// <returns>Cost value</returns>
    protected abstract float Heuristic(T p);

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear A* storage.
    /// This will be called every time before a search starts and before any other user functions are called.
    /// Optional override when using domain-optimized storage.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void StorageClear()
    {
        if (m_defaultStorage == null)
        {
            m_defaultStorage = new Dictionary<T, object>();
        }
        else
        {
            m_defaultStorage.Clear();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve data from storage at given point.
    /// Optional override when using domain-optimized storage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Point to retrieve data at</param>
    /// <returns>Data stored for point p or null if nothing stored</returns>
    protected virtual object StorageGet(T p)
    {
        object data;
        m_defaultStorage.TryGetValue(p, out data);
        return data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add data to storage at given point.
    /// There will never be any data already stored at that point.
    /// Optional override when using domain-optimized storage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Point to add data at</param>
    /// <param name="data">Data to add</param>
    protected virtual void StorageAdd(T p, object data)
    {
        m_defaultStorage.Add(p, data);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Interface

    /// <summary>
    /// Find best path from start to nearest goal.
    /// Goal is any point for which Heuristic override returns 0.
    /// If maxPositionsToCheck limit is reached, best path found so far is returned.
    /// If there is no path to goal, path to a point nearest to goal is returned instead.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Path will contain steps to reach goal from start in reverse order (first step at the end of collection)</param>
    /// <param name="start">Starting point to search for path</param>
    /// <param name="maxPositionsToCheck">Maximum number of positions to check</param>
    /// <returns>True when path to goal was found, false if partial path only</returns>
    public bool FindPath(ICollection<T> path, T start, int maxPositionsToCheck = int.MaxValue)
    {
        // Check arguments
        if (path == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
        }

        // Reset cache and storage
        path.Clear();
        m_nodesCacheIndex = 0;
        m_openHeap.Clear();
        StorageClear();

        // Put start node
        Node startNode = NewNode(start, default(T), 0, 0);
        StorageAdd(start, startNode);
        HeapEnqueue(startNode);

        // Astar loop
        Node bestNode = null;
        int checkedPositions = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            // Get next node from heap
            Node currentNode = m_openHeap.Count > 0 ? HeapDequeue() : null;

            // Check end conditions
            if (currentNode == null || checkedPositions >= maxPositionsToCheck)
            {
                // No more nodes or limit reached, path not found, return path to best node if possible
                if (bestNode != null)
                {
                    BuildPathFromEndNode(path, startNode, bestNode);
                }
                return false;
            }
            else if (Heuristic(currentNode.Position) <= 0)
            {
                // Node is goal, return path
                BuildPathFromEndNode(path, startNode, currentNode);
                return true;
            }

            // Remember node with best heuristic; ignore start node
            if (currentNode != startNode && (bestNode == null || currentNode.H < bestNode.H))
            {
                bestNode = currentNode;
            }

            // Move current node from open to closed in the storage
            currentNode.IsClosed = true;
            ++checkedPositions;

            // Try all neighbors
            m_neighbors.Clear();
            Neighbors(currentNode.Position, m_neighbors);
            for (int i = 0; i < m_neighbors.Count; ++i)
            {
                // Get position
                T position = m_neighbors[i];

                // Get existing node at position, if any
                Node node = (Node)StorageGet(position);

                // If position was already analyzed, ignore step
                if (node != null && node.IsClosed == true)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // If position is not passable, ignore step
                float cost = Cost(currentNode.Position, position);
                if (cost == float.PositiveInfinity)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Calculate A* values
                float g = currentNode.G + cost;
                float h = Heuristic(position);

                // Update or create new node at position
                if (node != null)
                {
                    // Update existing node if better
                    if (g < node.G)
                    {
                        node.G = g;
                        node.F = g + node.H;
                        node.PreviousPosition = currentNode.Position;
                        HeapUpdate(node);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create new open node if not yet exists
                    node = NewNode(position, currentNode.Position, g, h);
                    StorageAdd(position, node);
                    HeapEnqueue(node);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Internals

    private void BuildPathFromEndNode(ICollection<T> path, Node startNode, Node endNode)
    {
        for (Node node = endNode; node != startNode; node = (Node)StorageGet(node.PreviousPosition))
        {
            path.Add(node.Position);
        }
    }

    private void HeapEnqueue(Node node)
    {
        m_openHeap.Add(node);
        HeapifyFromPosToStart(m_openHeap.Count - 1);
    }

    private Node HeapDequeue()
    {
        Node result = m_openHeap[0];
        if (m_openHeap.Count <= 1)
        {
            m_openHeap.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            m_openHeap[0] = m_openHeap[m_openHeap.Count - 1];
            m_openHeap.RemoveAt(m_openHeap.Count - 1);
            HeapifyFromPosToEnd(0);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void HeapUpdate(Node node)
    {
        int pos = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_openHeap.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (m_openHeap[i] == node)
            {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        HeapifyFromPosToStart(pos);
    }

    private void HeapifyFromPosToEnd(int pos)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int smallest = pos;
            int left = 2 * pos + 1;
            int right = 2 * pos + 2;
            if (left < m_openHeap.Count && m_openHeap[left].F < m_openHeap[smallest].F)
                smallest = left;
            if (right < m_openHeap.Count && m_openHeap[right].F < m_openHeap[smallest].F)
                smallest = right;
            if (smallest != pos)
            {
                Node tmp = m_openHeap[smallest];
                m_openHeap[smallest] = m_openHeap[pos];
                m_openHeap[pos] = tmp;
                pos = smallest;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void HeapifyFromPosToStart(int pos)
    {
        int childPos = pos;
        while (childPos > 0)
        {
            int parentPos = (childPos - 1) / 2;
            Node parentNode = m_openHeap[parentPos];
            Node childNode = m_openHeap[childPos];
            if (parentNode.F > childNode.F)
            {
                m_openHeap[parentPos] = childNode;
                m_openHeap[childPos] = parentNode;
                childPos = parentPos;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private Node NewNode(T position, T previousPosition, float g, float h)
    {
        while (m_nodesCacheIndex >= m_nodesCache.Count)
        {
            m_nodesCache.Add(new Node());
        }
        Node node = m_nodesCache[m_nodesCacheIndex++];
        node.Position = position;
        node.PreviousPosition = previousPosition;
        node.F = g + h;
        node.G = g;
        node.H = h;
        node.IsClosed = false;
        return node;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This is extremely good and well thought out. Thank you. There are many other implementations but it takes too much effort to tease out the algorithm from the specifics of the implementation. This code is reusable and clean.